# Get URL of a file in Google Drive thanks to its name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

First of all, sorry for my English (I'm learning ^^).

I want to have a script to find a file's url thanks to the name of the file, and then put the URL in my sheet called 'Suivi-des-devis!' in the range 'O2'

The files are always called "FAC_quote number", and the quote number is in sheet 'DEVIS!' in 'E6'.

I really tried to create the script alone, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me to correct the script please ?

```
  function testenregistrement() {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var f2 = doc.getSheetByName('Suivi-des-devis');
    var dossier2 = DriveApp.getFolderById("1WNyBdexfylgflnDeKtMcdIN-eS578dlH")
    var nom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DEVIS').getRange('E6').getValue();
    var files = dossier2.getFilesByName("FAC_" + nom).getUrl(); f2.getRange('O2').setValue(files);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider adding the code directly in the question, and format it as `code`.

Comment: I tried to correct my post but I don't find the option 'modify'

Comment: Click `Edit`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Folder.getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByName(String)) method gets a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) object. Use the [FileIterator.next()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#next()) method to get a *file*, like this:

`var files = dossier2.getFilesByName("FAC_" + nom).next().getUrl();`